# Multi resolution development with MonoGame

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, monogame

I develop mobile applications with cross platforms Monogame.

Now I have a real problem with the resolution of the screens (Phone and Tablet) in different OS (iOS, Android, WP), so my questions are:

1. What are the resolutions and the screens sizes to be considered for Phone and Tablet in different OS (iOS, Android, WP) .
2. What is the aproach to adopt for a maximum share code between versions of applications (eg: #if, #else ...).
3. Should I use resources (images, GUI , ...) for each version of an application.

Answer (score 0):

1) There are lots of resolutions to consider. You can find lists of standard resolutions in a few places:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Apple

But [don't panic about it too much](http://www.localytics.com/blog/2012/android-not-as-fragmented-as-many-think/)

2) Unfortunately, there's currently no really great approach to code sharing, they all have some problems. You basically have 2 options. Either [use file linking as recommended by Xamarin](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/) or [build MonoGame from custom source and use Portable Class Libraries](http://www.craftworkgames.com/blog/day-6-running-with-monogame-portable/) as I have done.

3) Not exactly sure what you mean? You can reuse the same content (images, sounds, etc) for each version using file linking.